# When retrieving the list of "master" objects, Backand Fails to retrieve "slave" objects

Tags: backand

When retrieving the list of "master" objects, Backand Fails to retrieve "slave" objects

app
springnutjs

When retrieving the list of "master" objects (the ones with the "collection, via" field),
Backand Fails to retrieve "slave" (the ones  with the "object" field) objects
even if it does work retrieving the "master" objects when retrieving the list of all "slave" objects

Answer (score 0):

In order to get collections ("slave") you need to use query parameter: deep=true. When calling a list of objects there is no deep at all, but when getting a single master with deep=true you will get all the children ("slaves"). 
For example, when you run /1/objects/master/1?deep=true you will get all slaves.
Running /1/objects/master?deep=true no slaved but only related objects.

Comment: You can read more [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/retrieve_data/index.html#deep-vs-lazy-load)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understood. List retrieval does not retrieve children (or related). Perhaps I was misled into expecting such children retrieval because of the API Try it Out to GET /1/objects/{name} Get list of items, which includes drop-downs for  "deep" "When set to true, brings the related items from the related objects", and 
"relatedObjects" "When set to true, brings the related items as a distinct group under relatedObjects node", actually producing URLs of the type https://api.backand.com:443/1/objects/AUXAUDITABLES?pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&deep=false&relatedObjects=false